# how to create/register menu items that can be added to menus later

Tags: theme-development, menus, themes

I noticed some popular plugins (i.e woocommerce as in the image below) have their own "menu items" that can be added to any menu.
how can I create my own ?
I checked the entire [theme developement handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/) and nothing there
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In past I added a few menu items to handle the book store.
Below am sharing a git link you can give a try, the solution is working and tested.

[Github Link](https://gist.github.com/nikolov-tmw/8698598)

If you face any issues let me know, or you can directly ask the repo owner.
Thank you